# Get Original URL in assets_rename_file / assets_move_file Hooks

Tags: assets

The documentation for Assets' assets_rename_file() and assets_move_file() hooks indicates that the first argument is "an object extending Assets_base_file class for the file that is about to be [renamed or moved]."  But when I call url() on that object, I get the URL of the already renamed/moved file instead of the URL of the original file.

The documentation for Assets' assets_replace_file() and assets_delete_file() hooks uses the same wording for its first argument.  But when I call url() on those objects, I get the URL of the file being replaced/deleted (which is what I expect based on the documentation).

What should the first argument of assets_rename_file() and assets_move_file() hooks represent?

What I'm trying to do is get the original URL and the URL of the renamed/moved file in the hook, but it doesn't seem possible to get the original URL.  So how do I determine which file is being renamed/moved?

We're using ExpressionEngine 2.5.3 with Assets 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets 2.2.1 has an issue of calling the hook at the wrong time - you should update to at least 2.2.2 and then the hook will actually be triggered before the rename/move operation with the correct $file variable.